# Gradle Daemon starting again and again in Android gradle sync

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

I cloned a project from git and it is starting Gradle Daemon again and again.

[image: 1]

The Gradle sync should be successful because it is a Google codelabs project.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to delete the .gradle directory. It is located in your "user" home directory. This will force Gradle to re-download all dependencies.

Also it might be smart to invalidate caches and restart. Go to File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart.